# Passing parameters to template for NavBar menu in Django

Tags: django, list, templates, navbar

I am trying to switch my head to start using MVC.

I have a Base HTML template, with an include NavBar code:

{% include "navBar.html" %}

So far, so good. Now, I want to send information to it (to the navBar.html template) regarding the Menu buttons. I have some simple buttons, and others with drop-button behavior.

My buttons are objects, they have information about name, href, position, etc, type (simple-button or drop-button)

So, I created a nested list in this way:

```
outer_list = []

for a in UserModule.objects.filter(user=user_id, is_active=True):
    inner_list = []
    inner_list.append(UserModule(a))
    for b in Submodule.objects.filter(module=a.module, is_active=True):
        inner_list.append(Submodule(b))
    outer_list.append(inner_list)

return {'outer_list': outer_list}
```

So, my first element in every inner_list is the head of the possible drop-button or a simple button depending on his type attribute.

The list at the end is like this:

- [0] Button-Simple-A
- [1] Button-Drop-A => [sub-button-1, sub-button-2, sub-button-3]
- [2] Button-Simple-B

and so on.

When I pass this outer_list to the template, the thing I have to do to arrange the buttons into the menu are crazy things. It has no sense to use MVC if I am going to write a lot of code in the template.

Until now, I am doing this over the template, and It is missing the first element identification, to recognize the button type, etc...

```
{% with isFirst=true %}
    {% for inner_list in outer_list %}
        {% for object in inner_list %}    
            {% if isFirst == true %}
                <li><a href=#>Drop_parent</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href=#>Drop-Child</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <li><a href=#>Static Button</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

It is not finished at all, but I believe I am taking the wrong way.

Good advice will be thankful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally,

I got something that works. I would like to know if this is acceptable or there is another better way.

On the view side:

```
    for a in UserModule.objects.filter(user=user_id, is_active=True):
        x = Module.objects.get(id=a.module_id, is_active=True)
        if x.type == 'drop-parent':
            list.append(x)
            for b in Submodule.objects.filter(module=a.module_id, is_active=True):
                list.append(b)
            list.append('drop_end')                     
    return {'menu_list': list}
```

On the template site:

```
{% for object in menu_list %}
    {% if object.type == 'drop-parent' %}
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">{{object.name}}</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
    {% endif %}
    {% if object.type == 'drop-child' %}
                <a href=#>{{ object.name }}</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if object == 'drop_end' %}
            </div>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Another question: Why adding the class identifier inside the list, I can not see the attributes in the template? I mean list.append(Module(x)) is not seen as an object Module inside template; otherwise, if I avoid adding the class I can access the attributes.

Thanks, I appreciate it